# React router only works with / path

Tags: reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, react-router

> Why work only root path and when i get to localhost:8090/about it
>   say's. Can not get localhost:8090/about

```
import React,{Component} from "react"
    import {BrowserRouter as Router,Route} from "react-router-dom"

var About =()=>{
    return <div>About us{}</div>
}

class App extends Component{
render(){
return (
    <Router>
 <div>
      <Route path ="/" component={About}/>
      <Route path ='/about'component={About}/>
</div>
    </Router>
);
}
}
export default App;
```

> main.js entry point(webpack)

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import App from "./components/App.jsx"

ReactDOM.render(

       <App />,
      document.getElementById('table')
);
```

> I'am use "react-router-dom": "^4.0.0-beta.7"

Answer (score 0):

Add a `Link` to your component, to change the route, Write it like this:

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Route, Link} from "react-router-dom"

class App extends Component{
  render(){
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
           <Link to='/about'>About </Link>
           <Route path ="/" component={About}/>
           <Route path ='/about'component={About}/>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Very helpful) th'x